# Objects in preview window do not show in the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I made a little tea cup. When i switch it to the rendered mode, it looks like this:

[image: Tea cup render preview[]

But, when I render it, there are elements that are missing:

[image: Tea cup final render]

What's wrong with what I have done? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are the plane and the lamps in the same layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reference this with the image below) You may be working with more than one Render Layer. Go to the "Render Layers" tab (2nd tab) and check if there is more than one entry inside the box (red box). If so, click the "-" (yellow box). After you've clicked on the tabs under "Layer" (blue box) for the desired layers you want to include in your final render, go ahead and click on "Save Current Layers for Render" (green box) - please note that this button is only for the "Amaranth Toolset" Add-On.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an add-on enabled? I don't recognize the *Save Current Layers for Render* button.

Comment: @ScottMilner that is from the [Amaranth Toolset](http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth). Very useful add-on I use myself.

Comment: @Grant You'll probably want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @ScottMiner Oh, I didn't even realize that was an add-on. I just got a bunch of add-ons that seemed this one day haha

Comment: i dont have any add-ons installed, so what should i do? @ScottMilner

Comment: @RainerAffan Timaroberts gave a link to the *Amaranth Toolset* add-on in the comments above. You can download and install it there.